# Can you import pictures from a locked iPhone with image capture?

Tags: iphone, photos

My cousin has forgotten his passcode for his phone, and is trying to find ways to get his pictures without resetting the phone and losing them.

Comment: This does depend on the iOS version and the Mac version Which it would be a good idea to put up here. I have done this with work colleagues who wanted their images backed up. Plugging into the Mac with the phone locked. But this was on Mac OS 10.6 and iOS 4 and 5.  Yesterday I plugged my iPhone iOS7 into a 10.6 build and the Phone told me the Mac was not authorised. I need to unlock the phone to proceed

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to the computer that syncs this device? If so, it will allow you to reset the passcode (and/or import the pictures without needing to unlock the iOS device.).

If not, you either have to crack the passcode or enter it properly. As there is a penalty for guessing wrongly (and perhaps a wipe after X incorrect guesses option that could be enabled), it's best to get help from someone who has knowledge of how passcodes (and tools to bypass them) work if the pictures are of value to preserve.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, and managed to solve it by opening iTunes, which would automatically try to sync my iPhone with the computer. I had to choose 'trust this computer' on my iPhone. Then I could access my pics on Image Capture.